# Ruby on Rails 5.2 How do I fix the mysql access denied issue on root user?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have no idea what is causing this issue, but root does have a password and I can't get the root to point to my Duelingpets duelpet user instead?
Here is what I have.

Here is the code:

> Mysql2::Error
>       Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>       Extracted source (around line #90):

Comment: Did you want to add some code? It is missing.

Comment: Did you make database in your rails project ?

Comment: The rails question helper prevented me from adding the code and this was the only code I was able to do. I kind of scraps this one and started over with a new server. Its better now but I am running into one issue a index of / problem. It won't display the running rails of 5.2.